# Llamadas a writer (LibreOffice) desde VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, libreoffice-calc, openoffice

Trabajo con Access y necesito manejar ficheros de writer .odt

Necesito una función que abra "fichero_ejemplo.odt" y sustituir una marca "{IMAGEN}" por una foto, pasando como parámetros la ruta del fichero y de la imagen (.jpeg)

He encontrado código LibreBASIC para hacer cosas similares pero necesito la traducción a VBA para la definición de objetos (Frame, Dispatcher) y después hacer las correspondientes llamadas.

Esto es un ejemplo de código en LibreBasic que hace algo parecido, sustituye cada aparición de "{IMAGEN}" por una foto. Algo parecido es lo que necesito pero en VBA para MSACCESS.

```vb
Sub BuscarImagen
SDescrip = ThisComponent.createSearchDescriptor()
SDescrip.SearchRegularExpression = TRUE
SDescrip.SearchString = "{IMAGEN}"

Frame   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args1(3) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args1(0).Name = "FileName"
'args1(0).Value = ""
args1(1).Name = "FilterName"
args1(1).Value = "<Todos los formatos>"
args1(2).Name = "AsLink"
args1(2).Value = false
args1(3).Name = "Style"
args1(3).Value = "Imágenes"

oVC = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ViewCursor

Imagenes = ThisComponent.findAll(SDescrip)
Count = Imagenes.Count

for i = 0 to Count - 1
  oTexto = Imagenes.getByIndex(i)
  oVC.gotoRange(oTexto.Start, False)
  NumCarac = Len(oTexto.String)
  NombreImagen = Right(oTexto.String, NumCarac - 2)
  oTexto.String = ""
  args1(0).Value = convertToURL("/home/fjcc/Desktop/EJEMPLOS/IMAGENES/" & NombreImagen & ".PNG")
 
  dispatcher.executeDispatch(Frame, ".uno:InsertGraphic", "", 0, args1())
  oVC.jumpToStartOfPage()

next i
End Sub
```

Ahora pongo código VBA que me funciona, abro un fichero .odt sustituyo {CAMPO1} por un texto cualquiera y después exporto a PDF por si os sirve de guía.

```vb
Public Sub utilizaopenoffice_Click()
Dim dbLocal As Database
Dim snpReplaceCodes As Recordset
Dim strCurrAppDir As String
Dim strFinalDoc As String
Dim strFichDestino As String
Dim varReplaceWith As Variant
'++++++++++++++
Dim mibusqueda As Object
Dim oservicio As Object
Dim Escritorio As Object
Dim document As Object

'++++++++++++++++
On Error GoTo Error_utilizaopenoffice_Click
Set dbLocal = CurrentDb()
strCurrAppDir = Left$(dbLocal.Name, InStrRev(dbLocal.Name, "\"))
      
' strFinalDoc = strCurrAppDir & "plantilla1.dot"
strFinalDoc = "C:\temp\plantilla1.odt"
strFichDestino = "C:\temp\plantilla2.odt"
strFichPDF = "C:\temp\plantilla2.pdf"
'también puede ser plantilla1.ott

On Error GoTo Error_utilizaopenoffice_Click
strFinalDoc = Replace(strFinalDoc, "\", "/")
strFinalDoc = "file:///" + strFinalDoc

strFichDestino = Replace(strFichDestino, "\", "/")
strFichDestino = "file:///" + strFichDestino

strFichPDF = Replace(strFichPDF, "\", "/")
strFichPDF = "file:///" + strFichPDF

  
  
Dim Args(1) As Object
 Set oservicio = CreateObject("com.sun.star.ServiceManager")
 Set Escritorio = oservicio.createinstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop")
 Set Args(0) = oservicio.Bridge_GetStruct("com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue")
 Set Args(1) = oservicio.Bridge_GetStruct("com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue")
 
 
 Args(0).Name = "Hidden"
 Args(0).Value = True

 Set document = Escritorio.loadComponentFromURL(strFinalDoc, "_blank", 0, Args())
 Call document.getCurrentController.getFrame.getContainerWindow.setVisible(True)
 Call document.getCurrentController.getFrame.getComponentWindow.setVisible(True)
 Set mibusqueda = document.createReplaceDescriptor



  varReplaceWith = "SUSTITUCIÓN HECHA"

 mibusqueda.setsearchstring ("{CAMPO1}")
 mibusqueda.setreplacestring (varReplaceWith)
 Call document.replaceall(mibusqueda)
'    Call document.store  'Guardamos los cambios  FUNCIONA OK
 Call document.storeasURL(strFichDestino, Args())   'graba con otro nombre
 
 Args(0).Name = "FilterName"
 Args(0).Value = "writer_pdf_Export"
 Call document.storeToURL(strFichPDF, Args())   'oDoc.storeToURL( sRuta, mOpciones()

 
 Call document.Close(True) 'Cerramos el archivo
 

Exit Sub

Error_utilizaopenoffice_Click:

Beep
 MsgBox "Ha ocurrido el error:" & vbCrLf & _
 Err.Description, vbCritical, "OLE Error!"
Exit Sub
  
End Sub
```

============ añadido  14/dic/2021
=== ejemplo de intento de insertar imagen. después de cada línea que da errror pongo el comentario con el error que da

```
 Set oSM = CreateObject("com.sun.star.ServiceManager")  
 Set oDesktop = oSM.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop") 
 
 Set oArgs(0) = oSM.Bridge_GetStruct("com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue")  
 oArgs(0).Name = "Hidden"  
 oArgs(0).Value = True  
 
 Set oDoc = oDesktop.loadComponentFromURL("private:factory/swriter", "_blank", 0, oArgs())  
 
  
 Call oDoc.getCurrentController.getFrame.getContainerWindow.setVisible(True)  
 MsgBox oDoc.Title  
 
 'con esto anterior abro un documento nuevo y todo va bien  
 'en el siguiente comentario te pongo comentado el error que da después de cada línea  
   

 Set oProp(0) = oSM.Bridge_GetStruct("com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue")  
 Set oProp(1) = oSM.Bridge_GetStruct("com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue")  
 oProp(0).Name = "FileName"  
 oProp(0).Value = "file:///c:/temp/pruebas/tmp-001.jpeg"   
 oProp(1).Name = "AsLink"  
 oProp(1).Value = False  
 
  ' Set oDispatcher = oSM.createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")  
  ' ERROR 438 EL OBJETO NO ADMITE ESTA PROPIEDAD O MÉTODO  
 
 Set oDispatcher = oSM.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")  
 Call oDispatcher.executeDispatch(oDoc, ".uno:InsertGraphic", "", 0, oProp())  
 ' ERROR: no coinciden los tipos  


 Call oDoc.Close(True) 'Cerramos el archivo
```

====== 15-dic-2021 código corregido
====== **SOLUCIONADO**

```
Public Sub insertaJpg_ODT()   '    INSERTA IMÁGENES EN ODT
 Dim doc As Object
 Dim strDoc As String
 Dim oSM As Object
 Dim oDesktop As Object
 Dim oDoc As Object
 Dim oDispatcher As Object
 Dim oFrame As Object
 Dim oArgs(0) As Object
 Dim oProp(1) As Object
     
 On Error GoTo Error_insertajpg
 strDoc = "C:\temp\pruebas\plantilla1.odt"
 strDoc = Replace(strDoc, "\", "/")
 strDoc = "file:///" + strDoc
 
 strPDF = "C:\temp\pruebas\plantilla1.pdf"
 strPDF = Replace(strPDF, "\", "/")
 strPDF = "file:///" + strPDF
     


 Set oSM = CreateObject("com.sun.star.ServiceManager")
 Set oDesktop = oSM.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop")
 
 Set oArgs(0) = oSM.Bridge_GetStruct("com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue")
 oArgs(0).Name = "Hidden"
 oArgs(0).Value = True
 
 ' Set oDoc = oDesktop.loadComponentFromURL("private:factory/swriter", "_blank", 0, oArgs())
 ' abre documento nuevo, sustituyo la llamada por una que abre un documento concreto
 
 Set oDoc = oDesktop.loadComponentFromURL(strDoc, "_blank", 0, oArgs())  ' abre plantilla en variable strDoc
 
  
 Set oFrame = oDoc.CurrentController.Frame
 
 Set oDispatcher = oSM.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")
 
 Call oDoc.getCurrentController.getFrame.getContainerWindow.setVisible(True)
 ' MsgBox oDoc.Title
 
  
  Set mibusqueda = oDoc.createReplaceDescriptor
  mibusqueda.setsearchstring ("{CAMPO1}")
  mibusqueda.setreplacestring ("SUSTITUCIÓN HECHA")
  Call oDoc.replaceall(mibusqueda)
  
  ' sustitución de un campo por un texto. funciona perfectamente
  

 Set oProp(0) = oSM.Bridge_GetStruct("com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue")
 Set oProp(1) = oSM.Bridge_GetStruct("com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue")
 oProp(0).Name = "FileName"
 oProp(0).Value = "file:///c:/temp/pruebas/tmp-001.jpeg"   ' "file:///<YOURPATH>/<YOURFILE>"
 oProp(1).Name = "AsLink"
 oProp(1).Value = False
 
 Set oFrame = oDoc.CurrentController.Frame
 
 Set oDispatcher = oSM.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")
 Call oDispatcher.executeDispatch(oFrame, ".uno:InsertGraphic", "", 0, oProp())
 
 'Call document.storeasURL(strFichDestino, oArgs())   'graba con otro nombre
    
 oArgs(0).Name = "FilterName"
 oArgs(0).Value = "writer_pdf_Export"
 Call oDoc.storeToURL(strPDF, oArgs())   'exporta aPDF

 Call oDoc.Close(True) 'Cerramos el archivo
    
 Exit Sub
   
Error_insertajpg:

   Beep
   MsgBox "Ha ocurrido el error:" & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "OLE Error!"
   Resume Next
   Exit Sub
     



End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Dónde te falla exactamente? ¿En qué parte del código estás atascado?

Comment: He añadido un nuevo trozo (14 dic 2021) con un comentario después de cada error de código

Comment: Ya encontré la solución (me ayudaron en otro foro). Lo dejo por si le sirve a alguien más.